# Restarting a rooted emulator is giving problems,

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I am trying to root an emulator, My ultimate goal is to change the phone properties like device name, manufacturer/brand name, imei number etc.
(modify build.prop)
I have tried rooting using this method.

https://github.com/0xFireball/root_avd/blob/master/README.md

The root works fine, I am able to root and make changes to the build but when I try to restart it, the emulator gets stuck in the boot loop

https://github.com/idanr1986/cuckoo-droid/issues/4

and this answer
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180468/android-emulator-how-to-avoid-boot-loop-after-rooting

Through which I realized that replacing the su file might fix the issue.
I replaced it and I am able to reboot but when I do, the root is gone and the changes don't stick.

I am using x86 non gplay api version 25
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rooting the emulator to change these properties.
I extracted the system.img using Superr Kitchen tool.

Then deodexed the full ram.
Extract the jar file(in this case framework.jar it contains telephony manager which has function for device imei)
After that edited the smali files to return the desired value when device imei is called( alternatively you can edit the java file and convert it into smali)
And then  build it all back into the system.img using Superr Kitchen